# Labelling Multi-"node" Path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to ask for a path drawn with the following command

```
\draw [->] (4) to [out=225,in=0] (11) to [out=180,in=-90] (12) to [out=90] (2);
```

How can I add a sloped label to the path. Furthermore, if I would like the label appear on the section between (12) and (2), what should I do?

Thanks![image]

---

Edited

My apologies. The code and generated output is as below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',node distance=5cm,font=\small\setstretch{1.0}]

    \node [state] (1) [] {A};
    \node [state] (2) [below=15cm of 1] {B};
    \node [state] (3) [left of=2] {C};
    \node [state] (4) [above of=3] {D};
    \node []      (5) [below=1cm of 3] {};
    \node []      (6) [left  of=4]  {};

    \draw [->,smooth] (2) to [out=225,in=0] (5) to [out=180,in=-90] (6) to [out=90] (1);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: If you can put your complete example we can tell you how. Right now I don't know what is which in the picture you have etc.? With five more lines of code everybody can copy/paste right away.

Comment: @percusse Thank you! I have edited the post. Please help!

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: `\draw [->,smooth] (2) to [out=225,in=0] (5) to [out=180,in=-90] (6) to [out=90]node[pos=0.8,above,sloped]{here} (1);`

Comment: @HarishKumar Do you wish to post it as an answer instead? As you have the right solution. If you re-post it as answer, I will vote it. Thanks!

Comment: @DominicHung: I did so. I missed your comment hence the delay.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the node with  `[pos=0.8,above,sloped]` as the options at the proper place

```
\draw [->,smooth] (2) to [out=225,in=0] (5) to [out=180,in=-90] (6) to [out=90]node[pos=0.8,above,sloped]{here} (1);
```

Further, with `positioning` library it should be `= of` not `of =`, With ese your code becomes

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',node distance=5cm,font=\small]

    \node [state] (1)  {A};
    \node [state,below=15cm of 1] (2)  {B};
    \node [state] (3) [left = of 2] {C};
    \node [state] (4) [above = of 3] {D};
    \node []      (5) [below=1cm of 3] {};
    \node []      (6) [left  = of 4]  {};

    \draw [->,smooth] (2) to [out=225,in=0] (5) to [out=180,in=-90] (6) to [out=90]node[pos=0.8,above,sloped]{here} (1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]